# Word Online and MS Word create new version after autosaved

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

We just migrated to SharePoint Online, and we have issue with Word Online/MS Word create new document version every time "AutoSaved" kick in.  Is there away we can prevent or stop Word Online/MS Word to create new version until the document get check in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can stop the autosave but if you can turn off the version settings from the document library but i dont think this is what you want.

MSFT turned on this feature due to putting extra layer for recovery.

You may select minor version settings from Document library.

> Behind the scenes, once a file is saved to a SharePoint Online or
>   OneDrive for Business site, AutoSave silently creates new versions of
>   the file in the document library to capture changes made by the user.
>   Depending on the versioning setting for the library, AutoSave creates
>   a new major or minor version of the file.
>
> Not every change results in the creation of a new version. Instead,
>   AutoSave uses a version for between ten and fifteen minutes before it
>   generates a new version and switches to it to continue saving.

Read more here: [AutoSave: Nice Feature, but Office 365 Tenants Need to Keep an Eye on Network Demand](https://www.petri.com/autosave-office-documents)